# JS - changing the colours of elements with spacebar presses

Tags: javascript, colors

I have a program that is supposed to this: If I press the spacebar, it is supposed to change the colour of an element to red, then, if it is still pressed after 700 milliseconds, it is supposed to change the background of another element to green. If I stop pressing the spacebar before 700 milliseconds, it should become black. Then, after one element becomes green, it should start a timer, and also "blink" the elements (quickly alternate between black and red/green every 200 milliseconds). However, it is not working properly. Here is my code:

```js
//This is my main.js file
var toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggle');
var redDiv = document.getElementById('red');
var greenDiv = document.getElementById('green');
var done = false;
var watchIsOn = false;//this is actually done in my timer.js

function blink() {
  redDiv.style.background="red";
  greenDiv.style.background="green";
}

function f1() {
  if ((watchIsOn) && (!done)) {
    //watch.stop(); This is a function in my timer.js
    redDiv.style.background = "#111";
    greenDiv.style.background = "#111";
    toggleBtn.textContent = "start";
    done = true;
  }
  else if ((!watchIsOn) && (!done)) {
    //watch.start(); This is a function in my timer.js
    toggleBtn.textContent = "stop";
    setInterval(blink, 200);
    redDiv.style.background = "#111";
    greenDiv.style.background = "#111";
  }
  else if ((!watchIsOn) && (done)) {
    //watch.reset(); This is a function in my timer.js
    done = false;
    f1();
  }
}

function f2() {
  //watch.reset(); This is a function in my timer.js
}

function green() {
  window.onkeydown = function(Event) {
    if ((Event.which == 32) && (!done)) {
      greenDiv.style.background = "green";
    }
  }
}

window.onkeydown = function(Event) {
  if ((Event.which == 32) && (!done)) {
    redDiv.style.background = "red";
    setTimeout(green, 700);
  }
}

window.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if (event.which == 32) {
     f1();
  }
  else if ((watchIsOn) && (!done)) {
    done = true;
    //watch.stop(); This is a function in my timer.js
    toggleBtn.textContent = "start";
  }
}
```

```css
.timer {
  background-color: #111;
  color: aliceblue;
  padding: 1%;
  text-align: center;
}

#red, #green {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 3%;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 41%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #111;
}

#red {
  float: left;
}

#green {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header><h1>My website</h1></header>
    <div class="timer">
      <div id="red"></div>  <div id="green"></div>
      <h1 id="timer">0:00.000</h1><!-- I have a timer.js file that calculates the time and updates it over here. -->
      <button id="toggle" onclick="f1();, watchisOn=true;">start</button>
      <button onclick="f2()">reset</button>
      <script src="timer.js"></script>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stacksnippets.net/js has a syntax issue on line no 42

Comment: I don't know why it is saying that, because 
" window.onkeydown = function(Event) { " is line no 42!

Comment: f1() function code generates this issue

Comment: I edited it, but still the same error is coming, this is SO frustrating :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are interested in knowing when the spacebar has been released, you should use `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` events. Your event handlers can then start and stop timers accordingly. Here's a "quick and dirty" solution that you can refine further.

```js
var stage = 0; // 0 = reset, 1 = red, 2 = blinking
var red = document.getElementById('red');
var green = document.getElementById('green');
var timerId1 = null;
var timerId2 = null;

function doBlink() {
  stage = 2;
  timerId2 = setInterval(function() {
    if (red.className === "") {
      red.className = "hidden";
      green.className = "";
    } else {
      red.className = "";
      green.className = "hidden";
    }
  }, 200);
}

function setupGreen() {
  timerId1 = setTimeout(function() {
    if (stage === 1) {
      green.className = "";
      doBlink();
    }
  }, 700);
}

function reset() {
  stage = 0;
  green.className = "hidden";
  red.className = "hidden";
  if (timerId1) {
    clearTimeout(timerId1);
    timerId1 = null;
  }
  if (timerId2) {
    clearTimeout(timerId2);
    timerId2 = null;
  }

}

document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    if (stage === 0) {
      stage = 1;
      red.className = "";
      setupGreen();
    }
  }
}

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    if (stage === 1) {
      reset();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.timer {
  background-color: #111;
  color: aliceblue;
  padding: 1%;
  text-align: center;
}

#red,
#green {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 3%;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 41%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #111;
}

#red {
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

#green {
  float: right;
  background: green;
}

.hidden {
  background: black !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>My website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>My website</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="timer">
    <div id="red" class="hidden"></div>
    <div id="green" class="hidden"></div>
    <button onclick="reset()">reset</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why you have used "===" instead of "=="?

Comment: You can use either in this case. The difference is that no implicit conversion takes place when you use `===` so for example `"1" == 1` is `true` but `"1" === 1` is false. Generally, you should use `===` and `!==` unless you have reason not to. For more examples, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: Ok, I made a few changes, like I put " red.style.background="red" "along with "red.className="" ", instead of changing it using css (it wouldn't work for some reason), and stuff like that, and it works! Thank you!